# Is there a quick way to deploy Outlook 365 profiles from an Exchange 2013 cutover migration?

Tags: exchange, deployment, outlook, microsoft-office-365

Is there a quick way to deploy Outlook 365 profiles from an Exchange 2013 cutover migration ?

We are currently in the process of syncing mailboxes within our cutover migration. Is there a way in which I can roll out new profiles for user so that they can start using Outlook 2016 with their new Outlook 365 config ?

Also are there any good quick setup guides for android and Iphones ?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft posts setup articles for mobile devices. Just Google/Bing "Office 365 Mobile Configuration"

This link currently works (but if it doesn't use search):  https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Video-Set-up-mobile-devices-with-Office-365-22ccc8e6-fa86-45ac-b83d-3e705a364845?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

You can use Group Policy to script the Profile Change, or use a 3rd party tool.  MessageOps has a little tool you can use called Config365 (http://www.config365.com/), it's run by an end user, but you could deploy that and have them just run it.

**Edit**

Config365 will use autodiscover to setup the client - so that has to be set to O365 before it will be useful.  It's a local tool - you may be able to use HOST file to point it to Office 365.

For Group Policy - you can push out these registry keys via a batch file to setup a new default profile (you can use whatever method you prefer to assign these keys).  It will add a new profile called "O365", then set it as default.  When outlook starts it should attempt to configure the profile with the signed in user.

```
reg add HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook\Profiles\O365
reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook" /v DefaultProfile /t REG_SZ /d "O365" /F
```

This assumes Autodiscover is pointing to Office365, otherwise, you will just get setup to your Exchange server again. In a cutover - you are moving everyone at once so you should be prepared to update Autodiscover and Exchange SCP records when you do this. You will update the Exhcange end point with the `Set-ClientAccessServer or Set-ClientAccessService -AutodiscoverInternalURL` command.  An alternative is to use the Office group policy admin template and disable the SCP lookup for autodiscover.

An additional tool you can look at is SkyKick - it is not Free however.

Comment: Thanks I have run that command on my account just for testing, but considering we have not yet changed the MX records is there a way of testing if my Outlook 2016 will load up with a 365 profile ? as I tried config365 which has given me an error on startup of Outlook which reads. "Outlook cannot log on. Verify you are connected to the network and are using the proper server and mailbox name. The Microsoft Exchange information service in your profile is missing required information. Modify your profile to ensure that you are using the correct Microsoft Exchange information service".

Comment: How are you suggesting to 'script the change with group policy'?

Comment: I may just pop Config365 on the shared drive and get the users to run it individually, I have tried to run the tool but I face an Outlook cannot logon verify you are connected to the network and are using the proper server and mailbox name. The Microsoft exchange information service in you profile is missing required info. modify your profile to ensure that you are using the correct exchange information service.

Answer (score 1):

What I did was use group policy to delete the users' existing outlook profiles by deleting the registry key `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\<version>\Outlook\Profiles` so they get prompted to set up a new profile when they next launch outlook.  Then they just put in their email address and password and away they go.

Comment: You can use that same key to just set a new profile, this way you maintain the existing one in the event you need to fall back to retrieve some settings or rules that don't come over to the new profile.